# How can I find the cause of pg_catalog.pg_attribute constantly being vacuumed?

Tags: postgresql-10, autovacuum, aws-aurora

autovacuum seems to constantly run against `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` for the past week+. This seems pretty odd since we aren't doing constant table changes.

How can I understand why it's doing this and how to stop it? I'm on AWS Aurora and PG10.

Comment: Login to psql console and disable autovacuum for table pg_catalog.pg_attribute using    `alter table pg_catalog.pg_attribute set autovacuum_enabled = false;`                                         pg_attribute store information about columns which you might be adding/updating as no of records cross autovacuum threshold it get trigger I recommend to kindly disable autovacuum in DB parameter group of your RDS and enable it for only those table which have heavy writes/reads

Comment: We have a Greenplum DB which is basically custom Postgres where we weekly vacuum pg_class and pg_attribute because it's rapidly growing and if we don't do this we get I/O pressure after 2nd week of last vacuum. So I think AWS got a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `log_statement=ddl` to double check DDL statements. Maybe application code is creating temporary tables.

Comment: your answer seem to be irrelevant as this set will only help on postgres log file to log only DDL statements nothing to do with autovacuum

Comment: My answer can be relevant if there is a lot of DDL that writes to `pg_catalog.pg_attribute `and as a consequence that can triggger more autovacuum activity on this system catalog. I find your answer more irrelevant than mine.

Comment: But setting this postgres logs won't records statement other than DDL which increase the risk for monitoring system